# How can I turn an array into an object with the name being the first value in the array and the properties an array of the subarrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

What is the best way to take a multidimensional array with an unknown list of elements and group it into an object to remove repeated values in the first element of the subarray:

For example, I'd like to turn this:

```
const arr = [[a, 1, 4], [b, 3, 4], [c, 1, 7], [a, 2, 5], [c, 3, 5]]
```

Into this:

```
arrResult = {a:[[1, 4],[2, 5]], b:[[3, 4]], c:[[1, 7],[3, 5]]}
```

I thought about sorting this and then splitting it or running some kind of reduce operation but couldn't figure out exactly how to accomplish it.

Comment: Reduce it into an object with keys as the first element of the subarray and the values as the 2nd and 3rd.

Comment: `const arr = [[a, 1, 4], [b, 3, 4], [c, 1, 7], [a, 2, 5], [c, 3, 5]]` - should that be `const arr = [['a', 1, 4], ['b', 3, 4], ['c', 1, 7], ['a', 2, 5], ['c', 3, 5]]` - because it makes a difference - oh, and you only need reduce

Answer (score 2):

You only need to use reduce (and slice), no need for sorting or splitting

```js
var arr = [['a', 1, 4], ['b', 3, 4], ['c', 1, 7], ['a', 2, 5], ['c', 3, 5]];
var arrResult = arr.reduce((result, item) => {
    var obj = result[item[0]] = result[item[0]] || [];
    obj.push(item.slice(1));
    return result;
}, {});
console.log(JSON.stringify(arrResult));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` like this:

```js
const arr = [["a", 1, 4], ["b", 3, 4], ["c", 1, 7], ["a", 2, 5], ["c", 3, 5]];

var result = arr.reduce((obj, sub) => {
  var key = sub[0];                         // key is the first item of the sub-array
  if(obj[key]) obj[key].push(sub.slice(1)); // if the there is already an array for that key then push this sub-array (sliced from the index 1) to it
  else obj[key] = [sub.slice(1)];           // otherwise create a new array that initially contain the sliced sub-array
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `reduce` and `destructuring` like this:

```js
const arr = [['a', 1, 4],['b', 3, 4],['c', 1, 7],['a', 2, 5],['c', 3, 5]]

function sub(arr) {

  return arr.reduce((obj, [key, ...value]) => {

    obj[key] ? obj[key].push(value) : obj[key] = [value]

    return obj

  }, {})

}

console.log(sub(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this solution better because it abstracts away the collation but allows you to control how items are collated using a higher-order function.

Notice how we don't talk about the kind or structure of data at all in the `collateBy` function – this keeps our function generic and allows for it to work on data of any shape.

```js
// generic collation procedure
const collateBy = f => g => xs => {
  return xs.reduce((m,x) => {
    let v = f(x)
    return m.set(v, g(m.get(v), x))
  }, new Map())
}

// generic head/tail functions
const head = ([x,...xs]) => x
const tail = ([x,...xs]) => xs

// collate by first element in an array
const collateByFirst = collateBy (head)

// your custom function, using the collateByFirst collator
// this works much like Array.prototype.reduce
// the first argument is your accumulator, the second argument is your array value
// note the acc=[] seed value used for the initial empty collation
const foo = collateByFirst ((acc=[], xs) => [...acc, tail(xs)])

const arr = [['a', 1, 4], ['b', 3, 4], ['c', 1, 7], ['a', 2, 5], ['c', 3, 5]]

let collation = foo(arr);
console.log(collation.get('a')) // [ [1,4], [2,5] ]
console.log(collation.get('b')) // [ [3,4] ]
console.log(collation.get('c')) // [ [1,7], [3,5] ]
```

Of course you could write it all in one line if you didn't want to give names to the intermediate functions

```
let collation = collateBy (head) ((acc=[], xs) => [...acc, tail(xs)]) (arr)
console.log(collation.get('a')) // [ [1,4], [2,5] ]
```

Lastly, if you want the object, simply convert the `Map` type to an Object

```
let obj = Array.from(collation).reduce((acc, [k,v]) =>
  Object.assign(acc, { [k]: v }), {})

console.log(obj)
// { a: [ [1,4], [2,5] ],
//   b: [ [3,4] ],
//   c: [ [1,7], [3,5] ] }
```

---

Higher order functions demonstrate how powerful generic procedures likes `collateBy` can be. Here's another example using the exact same `collateBy` procedure but performing a very different collation

```js
const collateBy = f => g => xs => {
  return xs.reduce((m,x) => {
    let v = f(x)
    return m.set(v, g(m.get(v), x))
  }, new Map())
}

const collateEvenOdd = collateBy (x => x % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd')

const sumEvenOdd = collateEvenOdd ((a=0, b) => a + b)

let data = [2,3,4,5,6,7]
let collation = sumEvenOdd (data)
let even = collation.get('even')
let odd = collation.get('odd')

console.log('even sum', even) // 2 + 4 + 6 === 12
console.log('odd sum', odd)   // 3 + 5 + 7 === 15
```